# Why can't I insert data into the database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

The second value `4` is insert

```
$time= time() + (1 * 24*60*60);
$rr = date('Y-M-d' , $time);
        
$sql = "INSERT INTO time_on_screen(wakeup, sleep) VALUES ( '$rr' ,4)";
mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your locale, `'$rr`' is something like `'2020-Sep-30'`, and that is not a valid MySql date. You need `'2020-09-30`'.

Try:

```
$rr = date('Y-m-d' , $time); // M -> m
```